# Why NOx will break the ozone sphere

Tags: everyday-chemistry, environmental-chemistry, atmospheric-chemistry

I've found that a reason for people to oppose supersonic aeroplanes was the $\ce{NO_{$x$}}$ gases it released would do harm to the ozone layer. So what is the mechanism of this?

Comment: The mechanism is rather complex, I discussed some of it already [for chlorine](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/9517/4945). In short, it basically removes the oxygen radicals from the ozone cycle: $$\ce{O2 ->[h\nu] O + O} \\
\ce{O + O2 ->[<M>] O3}\\
\ce{O3 ->[h\nu] O + O2}$$

Comment: Don't UV and cosmic radiation also produce NOx?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Introduction to Atmospheric Chemistry, by Daniel J. Jacob, Princeton University Press, 1999,Chapter 10](http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/people/faculty/djj/book/bookchap10.html),

> An important component of aircraft exhaust is nitric oxide ($\ce{NO}$) formed by oxidation of atmospheric $\ce{N2}$ at the high temperatures of the aircraft engine. In the stratosphere $\ce{NO}$ reacts rapidly with $\ce{O3}$ to produce $\ce{NO2}$, which then photolyzes:
>
> $$\ce{NO + O3 -> NO2 + O2}$$
> $$\ce{NO2 + $h\nu$ -> NO + O}$$

Note that there is no net consumption of $\ce{NO_x}$, thus it is able to act as a catalyst such that a single $\ce{NO_x}$ molecule can destroy many molecules of ozone by these reactions.